# Number of sets have the property of unions and intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following problem statement is really unclear to me. Can someone clarify what it is exactly that I need to find here to solve the problem? Or help find a starting point, I think its just the wording of the problem that is not clear to me. Thanks!

Determine, with proof, the number of ordered triples (A1, A2, A3) of sets which have the property that
(i) A1 ⋃ A2 ⋃ A3 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, and
(ii)    A1 ⋂ A2 ⋂ A3 = ∅.

Express the answer in the form 2(a) 3(b) 5(c) 7(d)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! It would be great if you also wrote what you have tried so far! How would you tackle such a question in an exam? This will both motivate and help other users to provide high quality answers.

Comment: Are you sure it is not "in the form $2^a3^b5^c7^d$". And as for a starting point, I would consider choices of $A_1$, and enumerate. It's not a great start, but if $A_1=\emptyset$, $A_2=\{1,2,...,10\}$, then any element of the power set of $\{1,2,...,10\}$ is a suitable $A_3$. Accounting for swapping the roles of $A_2$ and $A_3$, this gives a lower bound of $2^{11}−1$ possibilities.

Comment: This would be simpler if there was a requirement of the $A_i$ to be non empty or if it were empty pairwise intersections. Are you sure this is not the case?